# Setting Defaults for geoms and scales ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Theming for ggplot2 makes it quite easy to relegate the need for multiple or repetitive `+ opt()...` lines. However, I would like to know if there is a way to define defaults for geoms and scale colors. Instead of having to write `...+ scale_fill_manual()` for each plot, I'd like to be able to set it and forget it. Similarly, I'd like to be able to set geom options so I don't have to retype (or forget to retype) things like `geom_text(...,size=3,color="white")`

Update:

For scales, it seems at some point that there was a method:

`set_default_scale("colour", "discrete", "grey")`

But this function doesn't seem to exist in the most recent version of ggplot2.

Comment: see http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2-dev/browse_thread/thread/fc838059c281e835?pli=1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is another method for this now. You can essentially overwrite any aesthetics scale, for example:

```
scale_colour_discrete <- function(...) scale_colour_brewer(..., palette="Set2")
scale_fill_discrete <- function(...) scale_fill_brewer(... , palette="Set2")
```

Now, your aesthetics will be coloured or filled following that behaviour.'

As per: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/w0Tl0T_U9dI

With respect to defaults to geoms, you can use `update_geom_defaults`, for example:

```
update_geom_defaults("line",   list(size = 2))
```

Comment: Note the "u" in scale_colour_discrete!  I just tried this without, and it didn't work.

Comment: I had an issue filed against this, but it looks like they're closing down old issues for lack of dev time. https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/799

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of anything useful for the `geom`s, but for the `scales`, one option would be to use the fact that components of `ggplot`s are all simply R objects that can be saved, stored and reassigned like any other.

So you could perhaps create your own collection of "default" versions of many scales, like:

```
sfmDefault <- scale_fill_manual(...)
scmDefault <- scale_colour_manual(...)
```

etc. with your desired default values. Put them in your .RProfile or wherever and use them as needed.

Comment: This is the method I'm using now, but, I'd still like a way to set a default rather than having to remember to `... + sfm`. Another reason I want this is because I would like to be able to share my code without sharing theming options.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Sorry for duplicating what you already know! I agree this isn't optimal for the reasons you set out. I don't know of anything better, though.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the default palletes, can also be achieved by setting options, eg.:

```
options(ggplot2.continuous.colour="viridis")
options(ggplot2.continuous.fill="viridis")
```

If you have defined a custom scale, say `scale_color_custom`, you would need to change the options as follows:

```
options(ggplot2.continuous.colour=scale_color_custom)
```

Notice that you are feeding the options a raw function and not a string. The string `"viridis"` is a reserved special input, but using a function is more generic.