# How to change default color scheme in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the default color scheme in ggplot2. That is, I would like to define a color scheme (say: viridis) at the one point in the script so that all subsequent ggplot diagrams will use this color scheme without having to call `+ scale_color_viridis()` each time.

I've seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174625/ggplot-how-to-set-default-color-for-all-geoms) featuring `update_geom_defaults(geom, new)`, but I could not find a way to explain this function to use a scheme such as viridis.

I have also tried to update the ggplot color, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504724/change-the-default-colour-palette-in-ggplot), but, as @baptise pointed out, this approach does not really work.

In short:

1. define new color scheme, eg., viridis
2. call ggplot subsequently without adding `+ scale_color_viridis()` but still this ggplot diagram uses the viridis color scheme.

Comment: As that other question already indicates, this is not really a feature ggplot supports. Basically it seems like the request as the existing feature request: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2691. The idea would be to set default scales with the theme that you can customize. But this still does not exist in production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like

```
options(ggplot2.continuous.colour="viridis")
```

will do what you want (i.e. ggplot will look for a colour scale called

```
scale_colour_whatever
```

where `whatever` is the argument passed to `ggplot2.continuous.colour`—`viridis` in the above example).

```
library(ggplot2)
opts <- options(ggplot2.continuous.colour="viridis")
dd <- data.frame(x=1:20,y=1:20,z=1:20)

ggplot(dd,aes(x,y,colour=z))+geom_point(size=5)
options(oldopts) ## reset previous option settings
```

For discrete scales, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019984/hot-to-change-set-global-scale-aesthetics-colours-for-ggplot/26020938#26020938) (redefine the `scale_colour_discrete` function with your chosen defaults) seems to work well:

```
scale_colour_discrete <- function(...) {
  scale_colour_brewer(..., palette="Set1")
}
```

Comment: I am worried to try this, as I don't know how to revert it to the default. @[ben-bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) any thoughts on that?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue after restarting.  If you wanted to make it more permament, you could add the line to your rprofile.

Comment: see my edit that restores original options. You could also look at `?scale_colour_continuous` to see that the default option is "gradient" ...

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, I could not find a similar variable for discrete color scales (the continuous kind of works too for discrete colors, as you showed in your example, but a discrete scale would be better)

Comment: @ben-bolker: Thanks again. I just discovered that ggplot2 uses viridis as a default for ordered factors: `mtcars$am_f <- ordered(mtcars$am); ggplot(mtcars, aes(am, cyl, color = factor(am))) + geom_boxplot()`. That's helpful, because I could not yet convince to redefine `scale_colour_discrete()` to use viridis in sensible way.

Comment: I use the 'paired' palette and would want to move one discrete jump up, how would I do that? I wanna start with the dark blue not the light blue. Do you happen to know? Thank you!

Comment: @canIchangethis, please post that as a new question (linking to this one if appropriate), with a [mcve] ...

Comment: I thought it is close enough but will do. Thank you!

Comment: Here is my new question @BenBolker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438348/r-ggplot-colorscale-how-to-skip-first-discrete-color-in-a-scale