# R: ggplot Colorscale: How to skip first discrete color in a scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to have a graph with a color scale, however the graph has certain deviations, where the first category is missing and then the color scale does not work any more. Is there a method to skip the first discrete color in a color scale?

I provide an example that does not work below. The first graph has category A in light blue, and the second B. But also in the second B should be dark blue.

I also found this question: [How to change default color scheme in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750310/how-to-change-default-color-scheme-in-ggplot2/53750568?noredirect=1#comment131401446_53750568)

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load('tidyverse')


first_column <- c("value_1", "value_3", "value_2")
second_column <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D")
freq <-c(23, 41, 32, 58, 11, 16, 19, 38)

df2 <- data.frame(first_column, second_column, freq)

ggplot(df2,                 
       aes(x = first_column,
           y = freq,
           fill =   second_column )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")

df3 <-df2

df3$second_column <- ifelse(df3$second_column == "A", "C", df3$second_column)
ggplot(df3,                 
       aes(x = first_column,
           y = freq,
           fill =   second_column )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")
```

Comment: Please edit your code; data frame `df2` cannot be created as the vectors are different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

(As noted in the comments, your dataframe couldn't be created as given so I edited it.)

You can change `second_column` to a factor and add `drop = FALSE` to `scale_fill_brewer()`. This will retain factor level `"A"` in the legend even though there are no values, which will keep the colors consistent across plots.

```
library(ggplot2)

df2$second_column <- factor(df2$second_column)

# ... unchanged ggplot code for first plot ...

df3 <-df2
df3$second_column[df3$second_column == "A"] <- "C"

ggplot(df3, aes(x = first_column, y = freq, fill = second_column)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

*Edited example data:*

```
first_column <- c(rep(c("value_1", "value_3"), each = 4))
second_column <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D")
freq <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 11, 16, 19, 38)
df2 <- data.frame(first_column, second_column, freq)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to switch to `scale_fill_manual` and use a named vector to assign colors to categories.

```r
library(ggplot2)

pal_fill <- scales::brewer_pal(palette = "Paired")(4)
names(pal_fill) <- LETTERS[1:4]
pal_fill
#>         A         B         C         D 
#> "#A6CEE3" "#1F78B4" "#B2DF8A" "#33A02C"

ggplot(
  df3,
  aes(
    x = first_column,
    y = freq,
    fill = second_column
  )
) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df3 <- structure(list(first_column = c("value_1", "value_3", "value_2", 
"value_1", "value_3", "value_2", "value_1", "value_3"), second_column = c("C", 
"B", "C", "D", "C", "B", "C", "D"), freq = c(23, 41, 32, 58, 
11, 16, 19, 38)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```