# ggplot2: How to set default formatter for scale_y_continuous()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like to use `scale_y_continuous(labels=myformatter)` (with myformatter my custom formatter-function) as default for every ggplot.

So I thought I could redefine the function `scale_y_contiunous`:

```
scale_y_continuous <- function(...) scale_y_continuous(..., labels=formatter)
```

But I get an error

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

So is there a way to define the default behaviour?

Comment: You could write your own theme for this... Even make it default.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Okay, but how do I define the default behaviour for the axis? I found `update_geom_defaults`. But this seems not to set the axis.

Comment: It would seem I was a bit hasty with the theme comment. It doesn't change the geom default values - as you've already found out, `update_geom_defaults` should do that. What is the command you're using that doesn't work?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I haven't used any command as I think `update_geom_defaults` is the wrong command. But the @shadow's answer works for me.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944246/setting-defaults-for-geoms-and-scales-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `scale_y_continuous` from `ggplot2` inside your function instead of your own `scale_y_continuous`. Otherwise you have an obvious infinite recursion. You have to specify this using `ggplot2:::scale_y_continuous`.

```
scale_y_continuous <- function(...) ggplot2:::scale_y_continuous(..., labels=formatter)
```