# knitr does not hook scientific notation in plots

Tags: r, label, hook, knitr

When using `knitr` inline, it typos `$\Sexpr{2.5e3}$` with `$2.5 \times 10^3$` which is pretty nice. However I miss the fact that this does not work for the labels in plots. I guess knitr thinks there are character and not numeric. Is there a way to change that ?

Comment: this is not going to be easy. You should definitely look into using the tikz device and something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610377/how-do-i-change-the-formatting-of-numbers-on-an-axis-with-ggplot

Comment: indeed I was hoping that I could tweek the `knit_hooks$get("inline")` by adding somewhere a `if(!is.na(as.numeric(x)) x <- as.numeric(x)` but I can't find the right place to put this

Comment: my point is that I seriously doubt there's any *automatic* way to do this for plots.  If you want to use scientific notation for plots you'll need to specify a little bit more about how you want to proceed, in particular: (1) native "plotmath" formatting or LaTeX/tikz? (2) base, lattice, or ggplot graphics?  `sfsmisc::eaxis` is useful.

Comment: I use `ggplot2` and `dev=tikz`; I use Latex notation everywhere in my labels already and works fine

Comment: But looking at the `.tikz` generated files, I think I got your point about "no automatic solution". I may have a try with `trans_format` functions of `scales` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I discussed in the comments, getting this to happen automatically isn't so easy, but it's not too hard to get your scales translated. `sfsmisc::eaxis()` is a good solution for base plots.  Here are some `ggplot`-style solutions:

If you want to use native `?plotmath`-style formatting:

```
##scale function for plotting y-axis labels
scientific_10 <- function(x) {
    s <- scales::scientific_format()(x)
    ## substitute for exact zeros
    s[s=="0e+00"] <- "0"
    ## regex: [+]?  = "zero or one occurrences of '+'"
    parse(text=gsub("e[+]?", " %*% 10^", s ))
}
```

Or if you're using LaTeX/TikZ (I'm using `Hmisc::latexSN()` here. It's a 3-line function, so you could just copy it if you wanted to avoid dependencies or hack it):

```
scientific_latex <- function(x,scipen=-2) {
    require(Hmisc)
    op <- options(scipen=scipen)  ## encourage use of scientific notation
    on.exit(options(op)
    s <- paste0("$",Hmisc::latexSN(x),"$")
}
```

Example:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(trait=runif(1000),
                time=runif(1000,0,1000))
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())

## make plot
breaks.y<-seq(from=0, to=1000, by=200)
g0 <- ggplot(d,aes(trait,time))+
   geom_point()
```

`plotmath` style:

```
g0 + scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_10,
                   breaks=breaks.y, limits=c(0,1000))
```

[image]

TikZ:

```
g0 + scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_latex,
                   breaks=breaks.y, limits=c(0,1000))
```

[image]

Comment: quite funny indeed I came with sort of the same solution, but copy/pasting the `inline.hook` functions of `knitr` instead of your `scientific_latex` : `scientific_latex <- function (x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    x = knitr:::format_sci(x, "latex")
    i = grep("[^0-9.,]", x)
    x[i] = sprintf("\\ensuremath{%s}", x[i])
    if (getOption("OutDec") != ".") 
      x = sprintf("\\text{%s}", x)
  }
  if (is.numeric(x)) x = round(x, getOption("digits"))
  x
}`

Comment: if your solution is better than mine, or different in some way (i.e. an alternative that some future reader might be interested in), feel free to post it as an alternative answer to your own question (self-answering is encouraged on SO)

Answer (score 1):

Well after @Ben Bolker comment, I add also my solution here, maybe more in the `knitr` mood as it is only sort of a hack to apply the `knitr`rendering to the axis label. Especially in a `knitr` document one often sets in the beginning `digits` and `scipen` and expects it to be applied everywhere.

So define in the setup chunk the function:

```
inline_hook <- function (x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    x = knitr:::format_sci(x, "latex")
    i = grep("[^0-9.,]", x)
    x[i] = sprintf("\\ensuremath{%s}", x[i])
    if (getOption("OutDec") != ".") 
      x = sprintf("\\text{%s}", x)
  }
  if (is.numeric(x)) x = round(x, getOption("digits"))
  x
}
```

which is just a mix of `knitr::.inline.hook.tex` and `knitr:::.inline.hook` with the final `collapse` discarded. Then modify the default behaviour of `scale_y_continous` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981207/ggplot2-how-to-set-default-formatter-for-scale-y-continuous):

```
scale_y_continuous <- function(...) ggplot2:::scale_y_continuous(..., labels=inline_hook)
```

Then from the above example:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(trait=runif(1000),
                time=runif(1000,0,1000))
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())

## make plot
breaks.y<-seq(from=0, to=1000, by=200)
g0 <- ggplot(d,aes(trait,time))+
   geom_point()
g0
```

I get by default:

[image: tikz picture]

which is exactly what `knitr` does to number given inline.