# How to customize the default palette of ggplot2 without pre-knowing whether data is discrete or continuous?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Q: Is it possible to set `scale_color_viridis` in the `theme` of ggplot2 so that users don't have to explicitly write `+ scale_color_viridis()`?

By default, `ggplot2` can automatically figure out the proper palette without the user specifying discrete or continuous. For example, both of the following codes would work with same `geom_point(color=xxx)`:

Discrete variable:

`ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=Species))`

[image: category]

Continuous variable:

`ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=Petal.Width))`

[image]

My purpose is to replace the default "black-blue" gradient colormap with `virdis`, so that I can enjoy both the smartness of ggplot2 and my own preference of colors.

[image]

---

Update:

With the hints from @jdobres, and bqast's [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bquast/5012e33f5d12a0f1a1aece0530a27009) I managed to make it work by doing:

`scale_colour_continuous <- viridis::scale_color_viridis
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +geom_point(aes(color=Petal.Width))`

Comment: Possibly already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944246/setting-defaults-for-geoms-and-scales-ggplot2

Answer (score 1):

As MLavoie pointed out you need to override the palette one way or another.

Another option, instead of adding `scale_color_viridis()`, is using `scale_colour_gradientn`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Petal.Width))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors=viridis(3))
```

[image]

If you need to use it often, you can store your scale (`scale_colour_gradientn` or `scale_color_viridis`) and save some typing later:

```
scv <- scale_color_viridis()
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Petal.Width),size=2)+ scv
```

Comment: My purpose is to avoid `+scv` you suggested. But still thanks for answering my question.