# Can't update geom_histogram defaults with update_geom_defaults

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the default colors and fills for all of the `geoms` in `ggplot2`. I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174625/ggplot-how-to-set-default-color-for-all-geoms)  and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944246/setting-defaults-for-geoms-and-scales-ggplot2) which helped me get started on changing the defaults.

However, when I try to change the default for histograms using `update_geom_defaults` or `update_stat_defaults` I get the error:

> Error: Can't find `geom` called "histogram"

Is there a way to update colors and fills for `geom_histogram` using `update_*_defaults`?

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
update_geom_defaults("histogram", list(fill = "black", colour = "black"))

update_stat_defaults("histogram", list(fill = "black", colour = "black"))
#works in ggplot call
ggplot(mtcars)+
    geom_histogram(aes(x=mpg), bins = 5, fill = "black")
#works for other geom_*
update_geom_defaults("point", list(fill = "green", colour = "green"))

ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg,y=cyl))

#additional arguments that do not work with either update function
neither <- c("freqpoly", "histogram",   "jitter","sf_label","sf_text")
```

Using version R 3.6 and 3.2.0 for `ggplot2`

Comment: see comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2456

Comment: @Ben thanks for the heads up, do you know anyway around that? possibly writing over the `geom_histogram` function with specifying fill and color args?

Comment: take a look at this as well: https://emanuelaf.github.io/own-ggplot-theme.html - what is your overall goal with ggplot?

Comment: @Ben my overall goal is to set a theme and color palette for my company, I am able to get the themes but having trouble setting the colors for each `geom` specifically if I try to set more than one color in the the `update_geom_defaults` I get inconsistent behavior. I realize that I am getting on the border of asking a totally different question here.

Comment: i wish i had more to offer. did you try what the other person described in github issue: update_geom_defaults("bar", list(fill = "tomato")) for histogram? i suppose you could redefine the ggplot functions (perhaps might lead to other problems), wish i could help more

Comment: @Ben yea that does work, but I might try to redefine the functions and see what happens. Thanks for your help!